# Changing port number caused import error Django

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-2013

My `django` project was working fine when I ran my project via command prompt and doing `python manage.py runserver`, but now I'm trying to debug so I'm running my project via visual studio 2013 and it also seemed to be working. I decided to change my port number so I right clicked on my django project and selected properties. In the properties tab I set `Port Number` to 8000. When I tried to run my project in visual studio I keep getting this error :

```
ImportError: Could not import settings '8000' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named 8000
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I then tried to revert back to random port numbers by not specifying `8000` as my port but it still gave me the same error except with a different random port number.
I've tried looking everywhere to figure out why but I can't seem to find much. When I don't have the port number specified then it gives me the same error except with different random port numbers.

Reading through the docs I even tried changing `os.environ.setDefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE","pm_app.settings")` to

```
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "pm_app.settings"
```

Comment: This is a problem with the way the app is running the command. I've never heard of running a python app in visual studio though. Why do you need it to help debug? I'd really recommend looking at Pycharm for any python projects, especially django; https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/

Comment: ... What? Settings are changed by editing the settings file, not by "changing the project properties", however that is supposed to work.

Comment: IMO, Visual Studio is not a great option for editing your project code much less trying to run it, or step through it. As @marksweb has stated, use PyCharm if you want something similar to Visual Studio, but remember, you can always: `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` and step through it.

Comment: i usually use pycharm but i can't remember the reason for using visual studio. It was all working but then as soon as I tried to change the port this issue started and doesn't matter if i revert my changes the issue stays. I need to solve this issue to be able to debug in visual studio since it has to run the app. Interesting thing though is if I ran the cmd outside of visual studio it runs it no problem on port 8000, but when i run it through visual studio it runs it through random ports

Comment: Looks like the Python plugin for Visual Studio has a bug and generates an incorrect command line when you enter a non-standard port. I don't think there's any solution other than waiting for a fixed version of the plugin to be released or switching to a different IDE such as PyCharm.

Comment: pycharm's intellisense isn't as good as visual studio's for me. A lot of times it wouldn't even work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the same error I fixed it by doing the following:

- **Right Click** on the project in the **Solution Explorer** and click **Unload Project**
- **Right Click** on the unloaded project again and click **Edit yourprojectname.pyproj** this will open a new window with the XML settings of the project.
- **Locate** the following XML node **PythonDebugWebServerCommandArguments** and **Remove** it from the XML.
- **Right Click** the unloaded project again and click **Reload Project**

Comment: I'll definitely try this next time I get this error. I just re-cloned the project from git and it seems to have gone away for now.